# Placeholder text issue in IE browsers(8-9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, placeholder

I am working on form(input field) validation.

**Problem -** IE browsers(8-9) consider the placeholder text as value and during validation it accepts the same value, however it should be considered as an empty value. I don't wanna use any script and to achieve it, I came up with below function. Can anybody improve the usability/scope of the function little bit more. Currently it makes input field blank everytime user enters the value. However, I want it to validate for first time when placeholder default text comes into action. Any suggestion?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="memberid" id="memberid" placeholder="Some Value" />
<a href="#" class="alpha-btn" id="search-btn">Search</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#search-btn').on('click', function(){
    if($.browser.msie){
        $('input').each(function() {
            var theAttribute = $(this).attr('placeholder');
            if (theAttribute) {
                $(this).val('');
                alert('Please enter value - IE');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Dude I don't wanna use any script for this. IF you have any solution apart form that.. please

Comment: Dude, you already **are** using a script for it. The code you've posted *is a script*. The third party ones I linked to do exactly the same as your code, but without the bugs.

Comment: :-) how funny is that.. instead of providing solution you are pointing out silly things.. i mean i don't want any third party script to be added in my code.. wanted to achieve it using my function.. if you could enhance.. it would be helpful.. otherwise many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`placeholder` creates problem in `< IE 9` so you can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) like

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="memberid" id="memberid" data-placeholder="Some Value" placeholder="Some Value"/>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#search-btn').on('click', function(){
    if($.browser.msie){
        $('input').each(function() {
            var theAttribute = $(this).data('placeholder');
            if (theAttribute == this.value) {// check placeholder and value
                $(this).val('');
                alert('Please enter value - IE');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: #Roshan thanks. this is working fine. problem, when user will enter the default placeholder text as value (i.e 'Some value') in that case, it fails.. any solution?

Comment: #Bug in that case it `fails` and it is not `valid too`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you want to do is to build a complete solution for placeholders in IE8 and IE9. To do that, what I suggest is to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), with the **input placeholder function** detection. So, you could use a function like this:

```
window.ie8ie9placeholders = function() {
  if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
    return $("input").each(function(index, element) {
      if ($(element).val() === "" && $(element).attr("placeholder") !== "") {
        $(element).val($(element).attr("placeholder"));
        $(element).focus(function() {
          if ($(element).val() === $(element).attr("placeholder")) {
            return $(element).val("");
          }
        });
        return $(element).blur(function() {
          if ($(element).val() === "") {
            return $(element).val($(element).attr("placeholder"));
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

This will enable placeholders for IE8 and IE9. All you need to do is to use it when you initialize your code.

```
ie8ie9placeholders();
```